# Banshee 2.0 - Can't hear sound

Tags: sound, banshee

Ubuntu 11.04
Banshee 2.0

I can hear the sound of my files from any other program. However, Banshee 2.0 (the Ubuntu new player) seems to have a bug or something, and I can hear anything.

Have anyone having this problem as well, or had this problem ? If so, how can it be solved ?

Comment: Maybe volume level for banshee is 0? Check in advanced sound settings, output tab, volumes per application

Comment: Where should I look for those advanced sound settings ? Inside Banshee ? On System > Preferences > Sound ?

Comment: If I go to System -> Preferences -> Sound -> Applications - I can see Banshee and the volume is at maximum level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

If we go to:

System > Preferences > Sound and under the tap "Output" we should choose the correct option.

Perhaps a last update as changed those settings.

Thanks Extender.